# How to implement custom django filter for aggregated data from related model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I've built a simple API using the Django Rest Framework

Two Models: Person and Hike (person is FK)

I have these PIP packages installed:

| package | version |
| --- | --- |
| Django | 3.2.7 |
| django-filter | 21.1 |
| django-mathfilters | 1.0.0 |
| djangorestframework | 3.12.4 |
| djangorestframework-api-key | 2.1.0 |

**models.py**

```
...
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name          = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name           = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Hike(models.Model):
    hiker               = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hikes')
    hike_date           = models.DateField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    distance_mi         = models.FloatField(blank=False)
```

**views.py**

```
...
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hikes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    all_hikes = Hike.objects.all()
    def total_mi(self, obj):
        result = self.all_hikes.filter(hiker__id=obj.id).aggregate(Sum('distance_mi'))
        return round(result['distance_mi__sum'], 2)

...
total_miles = serializers.SerializerMethodField('total_mi')

...
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('id','first_name','last_name','hikes','total_miles')
```

**filters.py**

```
class HikerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    hiker = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name="hiker",
                                             queryset=Person.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Hike
        fields = {
            'hiker': ['exact'],
            'hike_date': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
            'distance_mi': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
        }
```

**sample data: hikes**

| id | hike_date | distance_mi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-11-02 | 4.5 |
| 3 | 2021-03-16 | 3.3 |
| 5 | 2021-08-11 | 5.3 |
| 7 | 2021-10-29 | 4.3 |

The Person view includes "total_miles" stat added via the Serializer (total_mi).

**Person endpoint**
http://localhost:8000/persons/2/

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Miles",
        "last_name": "Marmot",
        "hikes": [
            2,
            3,
            5,
            7
        ],
        "total_miles": 17.4,
    },
```

Currently, the "total_miles" is for all years.

My QUESTION: how can I filter "total_miles" (float) and "hikes" (list) in the Person view by a specific year by passing a URL argument?

*e.g. http://localhost:8000/persons/2/?year=2020 > "total_miles": 4.5,*

*e.g. http://localhost:8000/persons/2/?year=2021 > "total_miles": 12.9,*

--
I was able to limit "total_miles" by year in `Serializer.py` with
`all_hikes = Hike.objects.filter(hike_date__year='2020')` but the year is hard-coded for testing only.

Can I pass an argument/var to the Serializer function?

Or can this be implemented with a custom filter?

OPTIONAL/BONUS:

Can the "hikes" (list of ids) in the Person view be filtered by Year as well?

*e.g. http://localhost:8000/persons/2/?year=2020 > "total_miles": 4.5, "hikes": [2]*

*e.g. http://localhost:8000/persons/2/?year=2021 > "total_miles": 12.9, "hikes": [3, 5, 7]*

Thanks in advance! Best~

Comment: I just wanted to make a note which is auxiliary to the question.

I am able to get all Hikes for a Person for a year (or any date range) via URL parameters:

localhost:8000/hikes/?hiker=2&hike_date__gte=2021-01-01&hike_date__lt=2022-01-01

Returns all hikes by person (id =2) for "2021"

Answer (score 0):

the request is already passed to the serializer's `__init__` and stored in the `context` attribute

So in the serializer you could do something like:

```py
year = self.context["request"].GET.get("year") 
if year:
    all_hikes = Hike.objects.filter(hike_date__year=year)
```

c.f.

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Comment: Thanks! This worked well for the "total_miles" on both the Persons and Hikes, i.e. passing 'year=2021'. Also gives me ideas for filtering the Hikes by Year.

In additional to total_miles, I also have total_hikes, total_elevation_gain, highest_elev. In my original implementation, I made one db call `all_hikes = Hike.objects.all()` outside these methods and used `self.all_hikes. inside the methods to calculate aggregates.

In order to implement your suggestion/fix, I make this call inside each method. So every time I fetch data, it makes 4 db calls instead of the original one. Is this bad?

Comment: Don't declare `all_hikes = Hike.objects.all()` as a class attribute, do it inside the method. Or you could access it from the Person instance: `obj.hikes.filter(....`

Comment: Sorry, I asked my previous follow-up question poorly. My original post just showed "total_miles" but I actually have 4 methods/4 calculations (total_hikes, total_miles, total_elevation, highest_elevation). Previously, I made one call to the database (as a class attribute) and performed the calculations on the data retrieved in the methods. Since I've now moved `Hikes.objects.all()` inside each method, I'm making 4 calls to the database, then doing the calcuations. Seems like poor app design to fetch that data 4xs. Anyway, I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented @pleasedontbelong's answer.

1. For *hiker > total_miles* - if `year` is passed, then *total* is calculated for that *year* only. if not, *total* is calculated for *all years*.

**serializers.py**

```
...
    def total_mi(self, obj):
        all_hikes = Hike.objects.all()
        year = self.context["request"].GET.get("year")
        if year:
            all_hikes = all_hikes.filter(hike_date__year=year)
        result = all_hikes.filter(hiker__id=obj.id).aggregate(Sum('distance_mi'))
        return round(result['distance_mi__sum'], 2)
```

2. For *hiker > hikes[]* - if `year` is passed, then list includes *hike ids* for that *year* only. if not, *hike ids* for *all years* are included.

I replaced `hikes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)`

with the following `get_user_hikes` method in my PersonSerializer:

**serializers.py**

```
...
    def get_user_hikes(self, obj):
        all_hikes = Hike.objects.filter(hiker__id=obj.id)
        year = self.context["request"].GET.get("year")
        if year:
            all_hikes = all_hikes.filter(hike_date__year=year)
        result = all_hikes.values_list('pk', flat=True)
        return list(result)
...
hikes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_hikes')
```

3. In order to reuse `year=2020` to filter Hikes, I added `year` to the existing `HikerFilter`.

**filters.py**

```
...
year = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='hike_date', lookup_expr='year')
```

Success!

http://localhost:8000/hikes/?hiker=2&year=2020

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "hike_date": "2020-11-02",
        "location": "Frog Lake",
        "state": "OR",
        "distance_mi": 4.5,
        "elevation_gain_ft": 1275,
        "highest_elev_ft": 6739,
        "alltrails_url": null,
        "blogger_url": null,
        "hiker": {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Miles",
            "last_name": "Marmot",
            "slug": "miles-marmot",
            "join_date": "2020-10-11T11:45:02-07:00",
            "email": "miles.marmot@wta.com",
            "profile_img": "http://localhost:8000/static/images/2021/11/01/hat_miles_2020-1.jpeg",
            "hikes": [
                2
            ],
            "total_hikes": 1,
            "total_miles": 4.5,
            "total_elev_feet": 1275,
            "highest_elev_feet": 6739
        }
    }
]
```